# Why does my xlabel not show up? (It's not getting cut off)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a plot and for some reason my xlabel is not showing up. I don't think it is getting cut off, because when I call `tight_layout` it still doesn't show up. Any idea what is causing this issue? Here is the code used to generate the figure with some made up data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))

Months = ['May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']

P = [220, 120, 50, 24, 54, 72]
T = [7, 12, 18, 24, 14, 5]

ax.bar(np.arange(1.5, len(P)+1.5), P, 0.5, label='Precipitation', color='k');
ax.set_ylabel("Precipitation, mm", fontsize=12)
ax.legend(loc=2, frameon=False, fontsize=12)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.arange(1.75, len(P)+1.75), T, label='Air Temperature');
ax2.set_ylabel(r'Air Temperature, $^{o}$C', fontsize=12)
ax2.legend(loc=1, frameon=False, fontsize=12)
ax2.set_ylim(0,30)

plt.xticks(np.arange(1.75, len(P)+1.75), Months)
plt.xlim(1, 7.5)
plt.xlabel("2013", fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
```

And an image of the figure itself (With the xlabel not present).

[image]

Comment: why dont you use `ax2.set_xlabel("2013", fontsize=12)`

Comment: I agree, that should do it

Comment: Ah, makes sense now. I was trying `ax2.set_xlabel("2013", fontsize=12)` before as well. Should have though to try the first axes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using

```
ax.set_xlabel("2013", fontsize=12)
```

instead of

```
plt.xlabel("2013", fontsize=12)
```

works for me.